# Cardinality discrepancy

Tags: mysql, performance, statistics

I have two, almost identical, databases and I am trying to figure out what is causing queries to perform that much slower in one of them. While investigating using the `information_schema.statistics` table I noticed that the cardinality column for one of the indexed fields was triple in size compared to the same column in the other database. e.g.
For the first database the cardinality is

```
+------------------------+-------------+
| column_name            | cardinality |
+------------------------+-------------+
| date_time              |      46202 |
+------------------------+-------------+
```

and for the second database:

```
+------------------------+-------------+
| column_name            | cardinality |
+------------------------+-------------+
| date_time              |      185052 |
+------------------------+-------------+
```

Since the cardinality is

> An estimate of the number of unique values in the index.

I got wondering about the unique `date_time`  for this columns. Turns out that they are the same (`select distinct date_time from table` = 54187).

So if the unique values are exactly the same, how come the cardinality in the second database for the column `date_time` is almost four times the one on the first database?

Comment: Refresh table statistic with `ANALYZE TABLE`.

Comment: I did but there is still a discrepancy. Now it is 79642 against 64046. I know it's much closer now but the unique values are **exactly** the same...

Comment: The difference You see can be determined by the difference in data store on the storage/engine level. If so, try `OPTIMIZE TABLE`.

Comment: I ran `OPTIMIZE TABLE` before commencing with the whole investigation of query performance degradation. What do you mean by "difference in data store". The databases identical and they reside on the same machine. They are both using InnoDB as an engine. Are you referring to the underlying file system maybe?

Comment: *What do you mean by "difference in data store".* Data and indices are stored in files, which are divided internally on the blocks containing records data. Block data distribution may differ (both data in block and block in file) cause difference in statistic. For example insert any data into 3 identical tables by the same query except unique Asc sort for tables 1, 2 and Desc for table 3. In common the files of tables 1 and 2 will be identical (with accurate to time stamps and hidden service fields), but table 3 will differ.

Comment: So the statement history is also responsible for the statistics in these tables.

Comment: @Niko - I don't thing the statistics are influenced by what queries were run before.

Answer (score 1):

- The cardinalities are estimates.
- They have limited use, so don't worry if the values are as far off as you see.

If you are worried that some queries are being Optimized inadequately, let's see the queries, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  There are many things that can be looked at; most do not involve cardinality.

A typical solution involves a "composite" index.  For example:

```
WHERE a=1 AND b=2
```

If you have `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)`, the Optimizer will use only one of the indexes and may use cardinality to decide between them.

If you have `INDEX(a,b)`, the decision is obvious, and cardinality is irrelevant, *and* the query will run faster.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I am using compound indexes. Eventually, my investigation revealed that the problem was with the `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` while sorting. There was a filesort which was using temporary tables and since the in-memory limit was 16MBs the sorting was using disk space for most of the processing. Setting this to the table size fixed the performance issue.

Comment: @Niko - Caution:  Don't set those to more than, say, 1% of RAM.  Over committing RAM leads to swapping, which is about the worst thing that can happen to MySQL.